# How to setup a Webpack Dev Server proxy in a Docker stack running Nginx and Traefik?

Tags: docker, webpack, docker-compose, webpack-dev-server, traefik

I try to setup a typical web development environment for our team using Docker and Docker Compose using mostly the images provided by wodby. So far my WordPress installation is running fine in an nginx container, happily communicating with database setup in another service container.

Here my `docker-compose.yml` to set this up:

```yml
version: '3'

services:
  mariadb:
    image: wodby/mariadb:$MARIADB_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_mariadb"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $DB_NAME
      MYSQL_USER: $DB_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - "./data/sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:delegated"
      - "mariadb:/var/lib/mysql"

  php:
    image: wodby/wordpress-php:$WORDPRESS_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_php"
    environment:
      DB_HOST: $DB_HOST
      DB_NAME: $DB_NAME
      DB_USER: $DB_USER
      DB_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
      DB_DRIVER: mysql
      PHP_TIMEZONE: Europe/Berlin
      PHP_XDEBUG: 1
      PHP_XDEBUG_DEFAULT_ENABLE: 1
    volumes:
      - "./public:/var/www/html:cached"

  nginx:
    image: wodby/nginx:$NGINX_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx"
    depends_on:
      - php
    environment:
      NGINX_VHOST_PRESET: wordpress
      NGINX_SERVER_ROOT: /var/www/html
      NGINX_ERROR_LOG_LEVEL: debug
      NGINX_STATIC_OPEN_FILE_CACHE: "off"
    volumes:
      - "./public:/var/www/html:cached"
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=nginx"
      - "traefik.port=80"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${PROJECT_URL}"

  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_proxy"
    command: -c /dev/null --web --docker --logLevel=INFO
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
      - "8081:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"

volumes:
  mariadb:
```

And the corresponding `.env` file:

```env
# Project Settings --------------------

PROJECT_NAME=wordpress
PROJECT_URL=wordpress.localhost

# Database Settings -------------------

DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
DB_HOST=mariadb
DB_NAME=wp
DB_USER=wp
DB_PASSWORD=foo

# Service Tags ------------------------

WORDPRESS_TAG=7.2-4.8.5
NODE_TAG=10-0.6.0
NGINX_TAG=1.15-5.0.11
MARIADB_TAG=10.1-3.3.8
```

In addition I want to use a Webpack Dev Server during development to build the assets of a custom theme. The following snippet adds a node service to the stack running the `serve` script from the `package.json`:

```json
  # ...

  node:
    image: wodby/node:$NODE_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_node"
    working_dir: /usr/src/theme
    command: sh -c "npm install && npm run serve"
    environment:
      LANG: en_US.UTF-8
      NODE_ENV: development
    expose:
      - "3000"
      - "8080"
    volumes:
      - "./public/wp-content/themes/child-theme:/usr/src/theme:delegated"
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=node"
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:theme.${PROJECT_URL}"

  # ...
```

The corresponding script in the `package.json` is just starting the dev server:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --inline --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check"
  }
}
```

That is working fine to serve static HTML files from the theme directory. The problem is, once I start adding a proxy configuration for the Webpack Dev Server, in order to serve my WordPress installation running on nginx instead of the theme directory, I receive the following error when I visit the corresponding domain (http://theme.wordpress.localhost:8000):

```
Error occured while trying to proxy to: theme.wordpress.localhost:8000/
```

In the logs of the node/webpack container the following error is given:

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request / from theme.wordpress.localhost:8000 to http://wordpress.localhost:8000/ (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

My configuration for the Webpack Dev Server in the `webpack.config.babel.js` of the theme:

```js
devServer: {
    overlay: true,
    proxy: [
        {
            path: '**',
            target: 'http://wordpress.localhost:8000/',
            secure: false,
            changeOrigin: true
        }
    ]
},
```

The problem is, that I still have difficulties to understand what exactly is happening internally in the reverse proxy container. I have the feeling, that some information is lost while webpack is “proxying” the request to Traefik. I tried using the nginx service name directly as target host for the webpack dev server with no success.

How do I proxy the Webpack Dev Server requests to the nginx server in my Docker stack?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Well, I am getting closer. I think you have to proxy to the nginx service container directly and not back to the reverse proxy. The proxy target of the webpack-dev-server should be "http://nginx" in my example. Furthermore I had to change the public url of the dev server to "http://theme.wordpress.localhost:8000" and disable any host check. Furthermore I have to define the WP_SITEURL in my wp-config.php, otherwise wordpress redirects to the address provided in the WordPress configuration. Feels a bit hackish though, that is why I haven't posted it as a solution so far.